# Git-hooks pre-push script does not receive input via STDIN

Tags: git, bash, githooks

The [git-hooks pre-push documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_push) states that the first line of *stdin* will be populated with the local ref and sha, and the remote ref and sha as such:

`<local ref> SP <local sha1> SP <remote ref> SP <remote sha1> LF`

However, my simple pre-push script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "params=[$@]"

read line
echo "stdin=[$line]"

exit 1
```

returns the following output when a `$git push` is run:

```
params=[origin [url]:[branch].git]
stdin=[]
error: failed to push some refs to '[remote]'
```

The parameters to the script are as specified in the documentation (name and path of the remote).  The error is expected because my script exits with a status of 1.  However, I can't seem to figure out why I'm not receiving the local and remote refs on *stdin* as specified by the documentation.

Is this a bug in **git**?  Or, am I missing something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apologies if this is stating the obvious, but if there's nothing to push, you won't get any lines on stdin. The sample `.git/hooks/pre-push.sample` has a while loop:

```
IFS=' '
while read local_ref local_sha remote_ref remote_sha
do
    ...
done
```

and that appears to work when I try it here with an echo inside that loop and nothing else - I get nothing when I have nothing to push, and output when I do.

Comment: I haven't checked yet but I'm sure this is exactly what's happening.  The problem is I was misunderstanding the convention you outlined above.  Thank you for clearing that up!

Comment: @dcow This would suggest that a small documentation patch to clarify the issue would be in order ;-) https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/SubmittingPatches

Comment: @PhilipOakley posted to the mailing list.  Would you be so kind as to take a look?

Comment: @dcow I thought it looked good, apart from one spelling "beilieve", and that somehow three copies were generated (any ideas?). I see Junio (maintainer) has done his usual thing of trying to ensure the clarification covers the other areas that maybe hadn't been considered.

Comment: @PhilipOakley the three copies came from me trying to update the initial patch.  The url linking to this question in the notes was wrong so I fixed it and replied.  The message showed up broken in gmail so I double checked everything and tried again.  It still looked the same so I guess it is just a gmail quirk.  Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Apparently there is another possibility: if the push is non-fast-forward but no --force was supplied then the script is called but without any input on `stdin`. If --force is added to the otherwise unchanged command line `stdin` is getting input as it should. This is still undocumented (unlike the arguments, thanks guys ;)

Comment: The comment by @stefanct seems to still be the case, stdin is empty for non-fast forward, rendering it impossible to figure out which commit is being pushed.

Comment: The code for this undocumented feature is in transport.c in the `run_pre_push_hook()` function: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/transport.c#L1297