# Why Git pre-push does not allow me to run the input selection but fails upon select command in my interactive script?

Tags: bash, git, npm, githooks, git-husky

I made an interactive pre-push git hook that before pushing allows me to bump the version in an npm package.

```
#!/bin/bash

current_branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed -e 's,.*/\(.*\),\1,')

echo "Pushing ${current_branch}"

current_version=$(npm run version -s)

echo "Current version: $current_version"

patch_version=$(npx semver $current_version -i patch)
minor_version=$(npx semver $current_version -i minor)
major_version=$(npx semver $current_version -i major)

# Choose the version bump type
PS3="Select the version bump type: "
select bump_type in "patch - Bump into ${patch_version}" "minor - Bump into ${minor_version}" "major - Bump into ${major_version}" "none - Keep Same"; do

  case $bump_type in
    "patch"*)
      # Increment version based on the chosen bump type
      new_version="patch"
      break
      ;;
    "minor"*)
        new_version="minor"
        break
        ;;
    "major"*)
        new_version="major"
        break
        ;;
    "none"*)
      echo "No version selected, skipping bump."
      exit 0
      ;;
    *)
      echo "Invalid selection, please choose a valid option."
      ;;
  esac
done

echo "Bumping version to $new_version"

# Update package.json with the new version
new_version=$(npm version ${new_version} --force --silent)

echo "Version bumped to $new_version"

echo "Keep package-lock.json up to spec"
npm install
git commit -m "AutoBump Version" package.json package-lock.json
```

But once I push into my branch:

```
Pushing dev
Current version: 1.0.3
.husky/pre-push: 17: Syntax error: "do" unexpected
husky - pre-push script failed (code 2)
error: απέτυχε η δημοσίευση κάποιων ref στο 'github.com:ellakcy/fa-checkbox.git'
```

Seem not to run, but if run manually works fine:

```
bash .husky/pre-push 
Pushing dev
Current version: 1.0.3
1) patch - Bump into 1.0.4
2) minor - Bump into 1.1.0
3) major - Bump into 2.0.0
4) none - Keep Same
Select the version bump type:
```

As a way for fixing the issue, I tried this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22585746/4706711

But seem not to fix the issue.

Comment: Running `dash -n` on the code produces the error `...:17: Syntax error: "do" unexpected`.  Best guess is that the code is being run explicitly with `/bin/sh` (so the shebang line is just a comment) on a system where `sh`  is `dash` instead of `bash`.  That is the default on many modern Linux systems.

Comment: @pjh : That certainly sounds promising. But the O.P. has included `#!/bin/bash` at the top of the script. I don't have significant experience with `git`. Is there a reason we see so many questions where a script is called explicitly naming the shell, i.e. `bash .husky/pre-push` ? Why not just `.husky/pre-push` Less code has fewer places to fail (-;! Good luck to all.

Comment: Maybe git explicitly runs on dash whereas I explicitly run in bash.

Comment: @shellter I did call exclusively in order to test it manually and compare it with the execution from git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for husky to use `bash` for running hooks, change `.husky/_/h` which contains :

```
sh -e "$s" "$@"
```

change it to :

```
bash -e "$s" "$@"
```

In case it's not possible to make above change, you can put following line at  the beginning of .husky/pre-push :

```
test -n "$BASH_VERSION" || exec /bin/bash $0 "$@"
```

Comment: But upon the default installation the contents of `.husky/_` are gitignored. Therefore not easy to configure upon multiple contributors in my project.

Comment: Why does .husky/_ being gitignored prevents you from making the change ?

Comment: Because it will work only on my computer. Each dev will run the same hooks and I want a reproducible result without affecting the default installation to much.

Answer (score 1):

`git help hooks` says pre-push invocation is

> Information about what is to be pushed is provided on the hook’s standard input with lines of the form:
> `<local ref> SP <local object name> SP <remote ref> SP <remote object name> LF`

so your `select` statement is reading the first pushed ref from stdin.

Add a `<&2` after the `select`'s `done` terminator stmt to get it trying to read fd 2, that's stderr which I gather is still your terminal.

Comment: That seems to be fixed upon https://stackoverflow.com/a/22585746/4706711. The issue was not the input buffer but that the script was not running in bash.